# Convert between input types in bash commands

Tags: bash, redirect, pipe

In general, I find using bash commands with each other (ie compound commands) or with variables to be fairly confusing. Nothing ever works the way I expect it to. Commands expect varied input types (eg echo takes a string while find takes a filename), and there are many methods of transferring information from one command to another (eg xargs, piping, here-strings (`<<<`), and command expansion ( `$(command)` )). When using commands with each other, I am never sure of the right way to pass information from one command to another so it will work as I expect.

Some examples: If I do `echo $VAR`, it expects the variable to be a string. If I do `grep pattern $VAR`, it will expect my variable to be a pathname, rather than a string. To get grep to view it as a string I would have to do `echo $VAR | grep pattern`. So, to get the same expected reading, I must input my information differently for different commands.

Another example: I recently wanted to search for commands in my `$PATH`. It took me a long bit of trial and error to figure out that I could do so using `ls $(sed 's/:/ /g' <<< "$PATH") | grep searchstring`. Since I couldn't pipe arguments into `ls`, it seems `grep` can read arguments from stdin and `ls` cannot?

Specifically, some questions I would like answered are:

1. How do I know what commands are expecting what type of input?
2. What is the effective and semantic differences between different methods of passing information between commands (or phrases)?
3. Can redirected input and output be helpfully used here?
4. How do I change between types of input (eg if it's expecting a
   filename, but I want to feed it a string instead)
5. What are the rules that my compound command will be parsed with?
6. Bonus: Where and how in the above methods can I employ bash expansion and the like (eg can I bash expand after piping in information)?

Answer (score 2):

Not to be nasty, but you have to put in some reading and playing time to learn commands.  The more code you write wrong then fix the more you learn.

There are many bash tutorials out there.  Go to one  and start hacking away.   There is no magic cure-all for learning UNIX command and bash.  Just like Windows, you have to use the interfaces and commands.

Comment: So you're saying this question has too large a scope? As per your suggestion, I have just spent a bit of time reading around and I'm not sure that's so... So far it seems to me that most of my difficulty could be solved by a breakdown of the different function linking methods...

Answer (score 1):

> How do I know what commands are expecting what type of input?

if you do look at the man-page of a command you can see what arguments are expected and if that commands reads stdin and so on.

> What is the effective and semantic differences between different methods of passing information between commands (or phrases)?

It depends on the command and situation. Sometimes you have the option to provide some text in a file or through stdin (e.g., grep `-f`), it is your call.

> Can redirected input and output be helpfully used here?

Yes

> How do I change between types of input (eg if it's expecting a filename, but I want to feed it a string instead)

From string to stdin, you do `echo $string`, for other way around use `xargs`.

> What are the rules that my compound command will be parsed with?

Not a clear question IMO, there are rules enforced by commands themselves and some preference due to the current problem.

> Bonus: Where and how in the above methods can I employ bash expansion and the like (eg can I bash expand after piping in information)?

You can do anything with bash :) But expansion on pipe input requires some `eval` and fancy stuff.